# Help with a problem with matrices

Tags: matrices

Hi everyone I've been messing with a problem with matrices and I can't get it to work. I think I am not seeing it the right way because else I get an 8 variable quadratic system of equations.

If $A$ and $B$ are $2\times 2$ matrices and $A^2 = B^2 = I$ and $$AB = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$
and $$BA = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

calculate 
$(A+B)^2$.

Any help will be very appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, type in TeX. Consider $(A+B)^2=(A+B)(A+B)=AA+AB+BA+BB$ and do the math.

Comment: thank you very much, I wasn´t sure if the matrices had the asociativity property (first lesson about this). And I was seeing it the whole wrong way :D

Comment: @chubakueno, yes, the associativity holds but the commutative, does not. Try to find out a counter-example. If you agree, please, accept the answer.

Comment: In some minutes I will, the web doesn´t allow me to do so now.

Comment: and note that while matrix multiplication may not be commutative, matrix addition is.

Comment: I've just formated the text using TeX but somebody should review it and accept it.